# Chrome recently randomly downloaded a file (20bytes long) when I clicked on a normal link on reddit(is this a virus)

Tags: virus

I clicked on link and chrome randomly downloaded a file and it went to my downloads folder .. I didn't click on it I just deleted it.

I started searching for any random like files and came across something called "Enlightened" that has an magnifying glass as the icon, said it was created right around the time the file was downloaded, and it is a .lnk file... I am unsure of what to do with this, how can I investigate it further?

Comment: Know that `.lnk` files _can_ be malicious. Can you provide the URL you went to?

Comment: it is a NSFW link so I can not provide it, but it was just a gif under gfycat url.

Comment: Is there a way I can see the contents of the .lnk file... currently it is gibberish

Comment: I'm not sure I have enough information to answer the question then. Sometimes browsers accidentally download resources when they shouldn't, which is harmless, but a `.lnk` file can certainly be malicious, so there is that. Without knowing more about what you clicked, there's no way to tell for sure.

Comment: can I pm you the link?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to open up private messages with new users here. However you can post it and then delete it after I reply that I see it (you can delete your own comments at any time). You won't get in trouble for posting the link in this situation as long as you're professional about it.

Comment: I am not seeing anything download. I'm guessing what happened to you was just a fluke.

Comment: I also should mention that I clicked on this link from a reddit search page... but don't you find it weird that I have a .lnk file called "Enlightened" similar to the url.. could be random but it was created around the time I cliked the link

Comment: Are you sure that the link you clicked on reddit was the same one you provided here and not, for example, a link-shortener or something like that which redirected you to that one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87862/discussion-between-scarecrow-and-forest).